# Where to get server down time in Weblogic server

Tags: weblogic11g

Consider, One of the `Weblogic managed server` was down between 10am and 11am due to some reason.
Is there any log available for it denoting when it was down(The time at which server was down)? If so where can i find it?
Or Is there a method available to monitor the down time in weblogic server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the weblogic console log with 'nohup.out' (linux) or monitor default console logs (windows).

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/logging/ConfigureAndViewLogs.html) may help in setting up a log from your Weblogic console.

Comment: Thanks Geetha. Can you please explain it more precisely.